How can I make sure that my graph's y-axis always starts at zero, hiding any numbers that are negative from view?
var fireCtx = document.getElementById('fireNumberChart').getContext('2d');
var fireChart = new Chart(fireCtx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: [], // Add your labels here
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Sensor Value',
            data: [], // Add your sensor data here
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    suggestedMin: 0, // Ensure the y-axis starts at 0
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    precision: 0 // Display whole numbers only
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});


I want to ensure that the lowest number on the y-axis is always fixed to 0. this is the JavaScript code I'm using for the chart

How are you adding your data? Why not just exclude negative numbers in your dataset?

Provide a link to the "chart" library you are using (including version number)

Also you can hide the negative data


  const ctxWithHiddenNegativeValues = document.getElementById('chartWithHiddenNegativeValues');

  const labels = ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'];
  const values = [12, 19, -3, 5, -2, -3];


  const hideData = (labelArray, valuesArray) => {
    const labels = [...labelArray]
    const values = [...valuesArray]

    const hiddenLabels = [];
    const hiddenValues = valuesArray.map((v,i) => {
      const isPositiveValue = v > 0;
      hiddenLabels.push(labels[i]);

      return isPositiveValue ? v : 0;
    })


    return [hiddenLabels, hiddenValues]
  }

  const [hiddenLabels, hiddenValues] = hideData(labels, values);

  new Chart(ctxWithHiddenNegativeValues, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: hiddenLabels,
      datasets: [{
        label: 'With Hidden Negative Values',
        data: hiddenValues,
        borderWidth: 1
      }]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        y: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }
    }
  })
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>

    <div>
      <canvas id="chartWithHiddenNegativeValues"></canvas>
    </div>




Or filter data


  const ctxWithoutNegativeValues = document.getElementById('chartWithoutNegativeValues');

  const labels = ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'];
  const values = [12, 19, -3, 5, -2, -3];


  const filterData = (labelArray, valuesArray) => {
    const labels = [...labelArray]
    const values = [...valuesArray]

    const filteredLabels = [];
    const filteredValues = valuesArray.filter((v,i) => {
      const isPositiveValue = v > 0;
      isPositiveValue && filteredLabels.push(labels[i]);

      return isPositiveValue;
    })


    return [filteredLabels, filteredValues]
  }

  const [filteredLabels, filteredValues] = filterData(labels, values);

  new Chart(ctxWithoutNegativeValues, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: filteredLabels,
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Without(filtered) Negative Values',
        data: filteredValues,
        borderWidth: 1
      }]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        y: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }
    }
  })
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>

    <div>
      <canvas id="chartWithoutNegativeValues"></canvas>
    </div>



